# Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I already check other duplicate title but that doesn't give me the answer to my problem. I'm having this error and I still can't fix:

[image: Screenshot]

When I click on the agent_dashboard (on the side) I notice this error.

```php
txtDisplayName = <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: agent/dashboard.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 28</p>

</div>;
        txtPrivateIdentity = <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: agent/dashboard.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 29</p>

</div>;
        txtPublicIdentity = <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: agent/dashboard.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 30</p>

</div>;
        txtPassword = <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: agent/dashboard.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 31</p>

</div>;
        txtRealm = <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: agent/dashboard.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 32</p>

</div>;
```

Here's my Controller Main_Controller/agent_dashboard

```js
public function agent_dashboard() {
  $this->load->library('session');
  $user = $this - > session - > userdata('user');
  $data['user'] = $this - > Model - > each_user_data($user);
  //var_dump($data);
  $this - > load - > view('agent/dashboard', $data);
}
```

when I var_dump($data) I can see that the data already pass to the View and this is my model Model/each_user_data

```js
public function each_user_data($user){
        $this->db->select('user');
        // $this->db->select('user_level');
        $this->db->select('full_name');
        $this->db->select('pass');
        $this->db->select('private_identity');
        $this->db->select('public_identity');
        $this->db->select('realm');
        $this->db->where('user', $user);
        $query = $this->db->get('t_users');
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Lastly this is my view agent/dashboard, I use jquery on this.

```php
<?php foreach($user as $u) {?>
            var txtDisplayName;
            var txtPrivateIdentity;
            var txtPublicIdentity;
            var txtPassword;
            var txtRealm;


        txtDisplayName = <?php echo $u->user; ?>;
        txtPrivateIdentity = <?php echo $u->private_identity; ?>;
        txtPublicIdentity = <?php echo $u->public_identity; ?>;
        txtPassword = <?php echo $u->pass; ?>;
        txtRealm = <?php echo $u->realm; ?>;

        <?php } ?>
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It's telling you line #28, which "fine" piece of code would that happen to point out?

Comment: that is the error sir, `txtDisplayName` can't get the data of `<?php echo $u->user; ?>`

Comment: I'm not sorry for the sarcasm so it would be in your best interest to point out important crap like that when posting your question so that people don't waste their time. Anyways, the error is telling you that `$u` is not an object. Before the `foreach()` loop in your view add either `var_dump($user);` or `echo '<pre>'.print_r($user, true).'</pre>';` and edit your question with the output. If there is something sensitive like the password then just replace that with the word password or whatever.

Comment: yeah I know its not an object but when I pass it to the view it is an object.. sorry don't know much about this.. that is why I'm seeking HELP

Comment: I see. Can you please do what I asked in my previous comment and add the output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

user is an array and you are treating it as an object. This is why it's giving an error, trying to get property of non-object (in this case, an array).
try :

```
 $u['user'] 

 $u['private_identity'] ...
```

Comment: I already did that but still getting this `Message:  Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: does it need to be like this `json_encode($u['private_identity'])` or just plain and simple `$u['private_identity']`?

Comment: use php function gettype($u) in order to find out the type

Comment: you can var_dump the php variables in your view as well.

Comment: its a string sir, thank you .. I figure it out how it happens its not an object. THANK YOU SO much